# Curved menu for Web app using CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

Is it possible to build a menu like below[(http://www.flickr.com/photos/rohitramesh/9632832969/)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF8cY.jpg)

using only CSS and JS? I am looking to make a web app for phones with a menu like that.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/svg try using svg

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Check out these html canvas context commands which will let you create curved "buttons" as paths:

- arc(),
- moveTo(),
- lineTo(),
- fillText()

Then check out context's isPointInside() to hit-test if the user has touched inside one of the buttons.